# One way syncing of 4 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, synchronization

This is my problem:

I have an old database, with no constraints whatsoever. There are a handful of tables I copy from the old database to the new database. This copy is simple, and I'm running that daily at night in a Job.

In my new database (nicely with constraints) I made all these loose tables in constraint with a main table. all these tables have a key made of 3ID's and a string.

My main table would translate these 3ID's and a string to 1 ID, so this table would have 5 columns.

In the loose tables, some records can be double, so to insert the ID's in the main table I'd take a distinct of the 3 ID's and a string, and insert those into my main table.

The tables in the old database are updated daily. the copy is run daily, and from the main table I'd like to make a one-to-many relation with the copied tables.

This gives me the problem:

how do I update the main table, do nothing with the already-inserted keys and add the new keys? Don't remove old keys if removed in old database.

I was thinking to make a distinct view of all keys in the old database, but how would I update this to the main table? This would need to run before the daily copy of the other tables (or it would fail on the constraints)

One other idea is to run this update of the main table in Linq-to-SQL in my website but that doesn't seem very clean.

So in short:

- Old DB is SQL Server 2000
- New DB is SQL Server 2008
- Old db has no constraints, copy of some tables happens daily.
- There should be a Main table, translating the 3ID and 1string key to a 1ID key, with a constraint to the other tables.
- The main table should be updated before the copy job, else the constraints will fail. The main table will be a distinct of a few columns of 1 table. This distinct will be in a view on the old db.
- Only new rows can be added in the main db

Does anyone have some ideas, some guidance?

**Visualize the DB:**

these loose tables are details about a company. 1 table has address(es) 1 table has contact person, another table has it's username and login for our system (which could be more than 1 for 1 company)
a company is identified by the 3ID's and 1string. the main table would list these unique ID's and string so that they could be translated to 1 ID. this 1 ID is then used in the rest of my DB. the one to many relation would then be made from the main table to all those loose tables. I hope this clears it up a bit :)

Comment: I'm a little lost on some of your terminology.  What do you mean by a "loose" table?  Can you give a functional example?  Also, what is the functional reason for translating your multipart id?  You can have a 3-column primary key on an MSSQL column, is there a specific reason why you wouldn't want to use that feature?  Anywho, an example would be really helpful.  Could be just me, but I'm having trouble visualizing your solution.

Comment: with a loose table i mean: a table which has no PK, no constraints, nothing. just a load of data. the reason why i want to translate the key to 1 ID: the old DB is converging. soon this will be a new system, with probably a new kind of PK, so this main table protects me from needing to change everything. Example on the way.

Comment: What about extracting the keys after your copy job and insert into your main table? mean with INSERT INTO (c1,c2,c3) SELECT ... FROM (http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7124.asp)

Comment: Sounds ideal for an SSIS package to do the whole lot (pull rows from old DB, eliminate duplicates/remove rows that already exist in new DB, push rows into new DB main table, push a copy of all rows into the "copy" table). How are you currently doing the copy?

Comment: i'm using a SSIS for the copy, i'm not sure how to add some SQL code to that. i'll need to check it out. @bitKFu: how can i first insert records, and then build the main table. when there is a constraint? this wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use EXCEPT to insert the ids that aren't in your main table yet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

So for example:

```
insert into MainTable
    select Id1,Id2,Id3,String1,NewId from DistinctOldTable
    except
    select Id1,Id2,Id3,String1,NewId from MainTable
```

Comment: oh this sounds very interesting!